# Select 10 rows closest to a field numeric value

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I've a contest question such as "How many people will participate ?". I need to select the 10 closest answers near this total participants.

I've a table called **answers** with an *ID* and *number* field.
Let's say the total participants are 100 and I want 10 results.

I need to select the 10 results where number is closest to 100. It should be above and below 100.

How could I do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the ([abs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)(delta))...

```
select id, number, abs(100 - number) as delta
from mytable
order by delta
limit 0, 10
```

Something like this.

Comment: +1, but note that if there's a tie at #10 (more than one person picked the same number) people get selected more or less randomly.

Comment: @Juhana true, you could add a second (and third and...) order criteria like id (assuming autonumbering: first one to enter the correct number 'ranks higher') or name or...

Comment: @Juhana: It won't be random (it'll consistently be the same every time), but it will be indeterminate (unspecified implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the proximity with the absolute number of the substraction;

```
$proximity=abs($answer - 100);
```

the smaller, the closer!